# Red/Blue Hat Prisoner problem but with a twist

Tags: logic, game-theory

### The Problem

There are many versions of this problem before, most have the prisoners standing in a straight line so that they can't see the ones behind them, but here it's different.

I was asked this twist on the question before in an interview and I don't think I fully understand if there's a trick or if the answer is just really obvious. I don't remember the exact problem statement, so I'll try my best to remember the exact phrasing.

> A group of 100 prisoners is each assigned a blue/red with 50/50 chance. Each prisoner cannot see their own hat, but can see the hats of *everyone else (all 99 others)*. Once they see the others' hats, they can bet on what color hat they have on. Each person gets $1 if they're correct, and nothing if wrong.

1. How do you maximize an individual's winnings?
2. How do you maximize the collective group's winnings?
3. What if you can bet more than $1? How much would you bet based on what you see?

Twists:

- Does coordinating beforehand help?

---

### My Answer/Maybe The Real Question.

I think this is a trick question. If every blue/red assignment is random (and you're sampling with replacement), you are basically asking "if I have 99 fair coin toss results, what is the probability the next toss is heads?" So there's no way to maximize either individual or group's winnings.

I'm pretty sure the question was "sampling with replacement". But what if it wasn't? If it's a finite number of hats, equal amount of red and blue let's say...

Then you just pick the color you see less of, right? Every prisoner does that as well, so no need to coordinate, maximizing individual's winnings maximizes collective winnings?

No clue how to tackle part 3 though...

Comment: Assuming the prisoners bet independently, your first paragraph is spot on.  You are done.  From a mathematical sense, once you conclude that the game is fair you shouldn't care how much you bet because the expectation is $0$.  If I asked you to make a bet on a fair coin how much would you bet?  Some people are risk seeking and would be some amount.  If the bet sequentially and hear each other's bets you can assure they all win or all lose if you want.

Comment: Hmmm... Do the prisoners know which of the others have placed bets? If so, we can actually maximize the winnings by using a strategy as explained very well in [this video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=N5vJSNXPEwA) (which requires coordinating beforehand)  As for part 3, since I'm _pretty sure_ you lose nothing if your guess is wrong, just bet infinite money (or as much as you want, if you're not greedy) haha

Comment: Ah, well yeah then let's assume for part 3 that the bet is +$X -$X outcomes for that!

Comment: @TheMather-orratherAMather no, the prisoners don't. Otherwise, yes I agree, it would be easy. (I never asked during the interview, but let's assume no)

Comment: @JoeVictor oh, okay... In that case, maybe your answer _is_ the best strategy. What about the bets though, do you lose money if your guess is wrong? If yes, I'm not sure what the answer to part 3 would be 

Comment: Interview was a long time ago, but I'm assuming yes, you lose the dollar amount you bet if you're wrong, win the same amount if you're right. Otherwise, like you said, we can just bet infinite money